# Client doesn't receive custom HttpResponseException from ApiController

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I've created an exception filter for my Web API controller actions, but it doesn't seem to do anything (even though it does get invoked).

**Attribute**

```
public class ExceptionHandlerAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        context.Response.Content = new StringContent("My content");
        context.Response.ReasonPhrase = "My reason";
    }
}
```

I've also tried:

```
public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
{
    throw new HttpResponseException(
        new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        {
            Content = new StringContent("The content"),
            ReasonPhrase = "The reason"
        });
}
```

**Controller**

```
[ExceptionHandler]
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [Route("MyRoute"), HttpGet]
    public MyModel Index() {
        // code causing exception
    }
}
```

**WebApiConfig**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Filters.Add(new ExceptionHandlerAttribute());
    }
}
```

However, when an exception occurs the client receives this:

[image: Exception Message]

Comment: Is it getting invoked?

Comment: Yeah it is getting invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to throw an `HttpResponseException` with the response from your exception filter:

```
public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
{
    throw new HttpResponseException(
        new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        {
            Content = new StringContent("The content"),
            ReasonPhrase = "The reason"
        });
}
```

Here's more details on [how to handle exceptions in Web API](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/asp-net-web-api-exception-handling).

Answer (score 1):

your API side codes are ok. but getting the response should be like this (using WebException catching):

```
string getResponse(WebRequest request, out exceptionOccured)
{
    exceptionOccured = false;
    try
    {
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        var stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        exceptionOccured = true;
        using (var stream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        exceptionOccured = true;
        // Something more serious happened
        // like for example you don't have network access
        // we cannot talk about a server exception here as
        // the server probably was never reached
        return ex.Message;
    }
}
```